# Manga where character uses his body as an inventory with special magic and can store items there, even absorb attacks and return them on the enemy

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

I remember reading this manga where there was a character who used special absorbent magic, which was limited to his body. If the magic was full he couldn't absorb more. The magic could only absorb items that were not larger than his body.

He used this ability to carry soda and snacks, but could also use the magic to absorb attacks; the absorbed attack would retain its speed and kinetic energy, so the character could blast it back at the enemy.

Comment: Was this an unusual or rare ability? Was he native to the world, or was it an isekai?

Comment: Nonexhaustive list of spatial magic users at https://powerlisting.fandom.com/wiki/Spatial_Manipulation#Anime/Manga/Manhwa

Answer (score 3):

*Area D: Inou Ryouiki* (2012).

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/manga/35721/Area_D__Inou_Ryouiki):

> The "prison survival action" story is set after the sudden emergence of special powers in certain pockets of humanity. To deal with these so-called "Altered," a mysterious remote island prison named "Area D" was built.

More precisely, the character being remembered is Kaito Yuuki. [The Wikia page about his power](https://aread.fandom.com/wiki/Deserted_House) says it all:

> **Deserted House allows Kaito to store both living or non-living objects within a separate dimensional space, referred to as the "Fourth Dimension"**, by having them make direct contact with his body; **the only limiting factor being that said item cannot have the same mass as Kaito himself.**
>
> Anything stored within this dimension is essentially frozen in time, meaning they're in the same condition as when they were first stored, such as **flying arrows possessing the same amount of momentum or a can of cola still maintaining the same cool temperature**.
>
> **Besides allowing him to store things inside his body, Kaito can also uses this ability for combat, absorbing incoming projectiles without injury and sending them right back at enemy**, giving him a good balance of both offense and defense even without using any of the stored weapons or tools.

[image: manga page, character describes his internal storage ability]
[image: following manga page, same character sends back flying arrows to his attackers from his body]

---

Found mostly by memory, I used to read those in high school. I couldn't quite remember the name, but I remembered the part about an island and powers, thus a quick search for `manga island powers` led me to the correct title.